# Rotating image view belongs to a RecyclerView on click

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

**NOTE: I solved the problem while I was writing the question so no answers needed. Still sharing this with the answer so that someone experiencing the same can benefit from it.**

I have a recycler view which contains image and 2 textViews. I want to rotate the image when it is clicked but some strange things happen:

Sometimes, the image is not rotated. And sometimes, I see some images rotated even though I didn't click on them.

The code for onClickListener:

```
arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
            showAnswer(getAdapterPosition(), arrow);
      }
});
```

The method it is calling:

```
private void showAnswer(int adapterPosition, ImageView arrow){
    Info info = infoList.get(adapterPosition);
    info.setExpanded(!info.isExpanded());
    if(!info.isExpanded()){
        arrow.setRotation(90);
    }
    else{
        arrow.setRotation(0);
    }
    notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
}
```

Note that, I also change the visibility of one of my textViews at the same time which works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caught my mistake while I was writing the "I also change the visibility of one of my textViews" part of the question. Where was I changing it? Not in the onClickListener. It was in the onBindViewHolder method. Therefore, removing the if-else statements from onClick and adding the last line in the following method solved my problem:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RuleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Info info = infoList.get(position);
    holder.questionTextView.setText(info.getQuestion());
    holder.answerTextView.setText(info.getAnswer());

    boolean isExpanded = infoList.get(position).isExpanded();
    holder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    holder.arrow.setRotation(isExpanded ? 90 : 0);
}
```